# Issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

Unable to open file explorer. Even the menu icon and other icons available on the right-side notification bar.

[image]

Comment: Was the upgrade completely smooth? No errors at all?

Comment: I had a network issue in between rest everything was smooth.

Comment: When I open the setting option instead of minimizing and cancel buttons, I can only see boxes.

Comment: Can you open terminal ?

Comment: Yes. I have added the picture of how it looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved!!

File explorer started working after-
 `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Icons were visible after-

```
sudo apt purge indicator-common
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
gnome-shell --replace &
```